# Error: 'image' is a required property (OpenAI's Dall E Create image variation API)

Tags: typescript, next.js, openai-api

I am trying to use Dall E Create image variation API but whenever I send a post request, it is returning me this error

> error: { "code": null, "message": "'image' is a required property", "param": null, "type": "invalid_request_error" }

I am using next.js and this is my code:

```
const [selectedImage, setSelectedImage] = useState<File | null>(null);

const endpoint = "https://api.openai.com/v1/images/variations";

async function onSubmit(event: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) {
event.preventDefault();
if (!selectedImage) {
  toast(t("alert"), {
    icon: "❌",
  });
  return;
}

const imageSize =
  selectedValue === "Small"
    ? "256x256"
    : selectedValue === "Medium"
    ? "512x512"
    : "1024x1024";

setLoading(true);

const headers = {
  "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
  Authorization: `Bearer ${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_OPENAI_API_KEY}`,
};

const formData = new FormData();
formData.append("image", selectedImage);
formData.append("n", String(number));
formData.append("size", imageSize);
formData.append("response_format", "url");
try {
  const response = await fetch(endpoint, {
    method: "POST",
    body: formData,
    headers: headers,
  });
  const data = await response.json();
  console.log(data);
} catch (error) {
  console.error(error);
  throw error;
} finally {
  setLoading(false);
}
 }
```

I am storing the image in the state this way:

```
const handleImageSelect = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const file = event.target.files && event.target.files[0];
    if (file) {
      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
      reader.onload = () => {
        setSelectedImage(file);
      };
    }
  };
```

Please tell me what I am doing wrong here

Comment: Did you find what was wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Looking throught nodejs sdk docs, I found that the sdk checks that the object is FileLike when attempting to append it to FormData. If it’s not FileLike, it gets interpreted as an object, which messes up the key that gets added to the FormData hence the error.

My solution was to just set the values expected by the [file like](https://github.com/openai/openai-node/blob/2242688f14d5ab7dbf312d92a99fa4a7394907dc/src/uploads.ts#L67C14-L67C24) check on the blob and things seemed to work.

```js
const blob = new Blob()
blob.name = "foo.png"
blob.lastModified = 20
```